# Django User Model one-to-one with other model and Forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-authentication

I want to create a model for teachers and he will has a user to login to the system. I implemented this by one-to-one relation between Teacher model and User model, but I can't get my head around making a form for Teacher model and in the same time I want to create user for him/her, please note I'm using CreateView generic view.

### models.py

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        (MALE, _('Male')),
        (FEMALE, _('Female')),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, verbose_name=_('Gender'),
                              choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    civil_id = models.CharField(max_length=12, verbose_name=_('Civil ID'))
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15,
                                    verbose_name=_('Phone Number'))
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name=_('Title'))
    user = models.OneToOneField(to=User, related_name='teacher_profile')

    def enable(self):
        """
        Enable teacher profile
        :return:
        """
        self.user.is_active = True
        self.user.save()

    def disable(self):
        """
        Disable teacher profile
        :return:
        """
        self.user.is_active = False
        self.user.save()
```

Comment: Do you want the form to be similar to how you see in Django Admin? With a `+` sign along side `OneToOneField` drop down? You can make that button open `UserForm` in a new window. Or, can you post what issue you're facing right now? How's your current forms and views look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a signal to create a `Teacher` whenever the user completes the registration form. A hint would be the following case, I am creating a UserProfile automatically after the user completes the registration form

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "User Profiles"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username



def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

By using the signal `post_save` whenever a new user registers, the function `create_user_profile` will run, and a new profile will be created for that user.

Another way would be creating a form for the `Teacher` model, and validating both forms, the registration form and the teach form on the same view. 
I didn't want to write the whole code with your case the teacher, but I wanted to give you a hint on how to do it. Hope it helps.